# how to display latest recent posts in my facebook page to my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

i have page on Facebook and I want to display latest 5 posts from my feed/wall on a page to my website. How to do this? I found this solution.. it is easy

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
```

and someone guide me to use **facebook api** and do it myself
what is the best way?

I use php mysql  to build this site

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is the PHP code. You need to place this in your template.

```
<ul>
<?php
//function to retrieve posts from facebook’s server
function loadFB($fbID){
    $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$fbID."/feed?limit=3";
    // Update by MC Vooges 11jun 2014: Access token is now required:
    $url.= '&access_token=YOUR_TOKEN|YOUR_ACCESS_SECRET';// *

    //load and setup CURL
     $c = curl_init($url);
     curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    //get data from facebook and decode JSON
     $page = json_decode(curl_exec($c));
    //close the connection
     curl_close($c);
    //return the data as an object
     return $page->data;
}

/* Change These Values */
// Your Facebook ID
 $fbid = "190506416472588";
// How many posts to show?
 $fbLimit = 10;
// Your Timezone
date_default_timezone_set("America/Chicago");


/* Dont Change */
// Variable used to count how many we’ve loaded
 $fbCount = 0;
// Call the function and get the posts from facebook
 $myPosts = loadFB($fbid);


//loop through all the posts we got from facebook
foreach($myPosts as $dPost){
    //only show posts that are posted by the page admin
    if($dPost->from->id==$fbid){
        //get the post date / time and convert to unix time
         $dTime = strtotime($dPost->created_time);
        //format the date / time into something human readable
        //if you want it formatted differently look up the php date function
         $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
        ?>
        <ul>
            <li><?php echo($dPost->message) . $myTime; ?></li>
        </ul>
        <?php
        //increment counter
         $fbCount++;
        //if we’ve outputted the number set above in fblimit we’re done
         if($fbCount >= $fbLimit) break;
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

Two things you must do for working out this script.

1. Make sure your server is cURL enabled
2. You will have change the Facebook ID in the script by yours.

* You can get the access token this way:

```
$token = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APP_ID.'&client_secret='.APP_SECRET.'&grant_type=client_credentials';
$token = file_get_contents($token); // returns 'accesstoken=APP_TOKEN|APP_SECRET'
```

Comment: This seem to not work anymore - `print_r($page);` before the `return` in `function loadFB()` returns an error stating an access token is needed.. Specifically, it returns: `stdClass Object ( [error] => stdClass Object ( [message] => An access token is required to request this resource. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 104 ) ) `.

Comment: what if result is blank??

Comment: How to get facebook id?  I am using my facebookid then the error is showing "The global ID 100006307471668 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead." Please help me out.

Answer (score 15):

1. Login to facebook
2. Go to facebok developers section "[Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)"
3. Register new app, you need only to register new app, all additional data is optional
4. Copy your App ID/API Key and App Secret from that same "[Apps](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)" section.
5. Copy [facebook.php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/facebook.php) and [base_facebook.php](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/src/base_facebook.php) files from [repo](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk/tree/master/src) to your server
6. Use [polymorphic query](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) to api, to request wall content from facebook account

   ```
   require 'facebook.php';
   $facebook = new Facebook(array(
       'appId' => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
       'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
   ));

   $fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT_ID/feed?limit=5');
   if (isset($fbApiGetPosts["data"]) && !empty($fbApiGetPosts["data"])) {
       // display contents of $fbApiGetPosts["data"] array
   }
   ```

   Replace YOUR_APP_ID with your app ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET with your app secret and YOUR_FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT_ID with target facebook account, you want to get posts from.

Polymorphic query basically is path/URL. More info inside previously mentioned facebook api [reference docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/).

If your target facebook account wall is public, you won't need anything else that this, to view them.

Comment: This should be the checked answer.

Comment: Seems to work fine - except it forces session start and then you receive Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by ( ... Does this have to be called as an ajax from the page where you want you latest post shown for instance?

Comment: @trainoasis This is old information. I have not worked with it for more than a year, there could be many updates and changes to Facebook API (or SDK), I can't really tell where is problem for you. I would explore Facebook API SDK source code and see section where it creates sessions, and see if it can be configured.

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble with Okky's answer here, and I found a possible, albeit not an ideal workaround.

Use an RSS feed of your Facebook wall, then simply parse it with an RSS reader of your choosing.

`https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?format=rss20&id=YOUR_UNIQUE_ID`

[Here is a quick way to get your ID](https://randomtools.io)

Answer (score 0):

So to mix up Okky and Deele answer, that both help me out, you must end with something that will look like this. I also add an anchor tag to link to the post url :

```
<?php
$fbApiGetPosts = $facebook->api('/YOUR_FACEBOOK_ACCOUNT_ID/feed?limit=5');
if (isset($fbApiGetPosts["data"]) && !empty($fbApiGetPosts["data"])) {
    //loop through all the posts we got from facebook
    foreach($fbApiGetPosts["data"] as $dPost){
        //only show posts that are posted by the page admin
        if($dPost["from"]["id"]==$fbid){
            //get the post date / time and convert to unix time
             $dTime = strtotime($dPost["created_time"]);
            //format the date / time into something human readable
            //if you want it formatted differently look up the php date function
            $myTime=date("M d Y h:ia",$dTime);
            ?>
                <li><a href="<?php echo($dPost["link"]); ?>">
                                        <?php echo($dPost["message"]) . "<br>" .
                                         $myTime; ?></a></li>
            <?php
        }
    }   
}
?>
```

Comment: Why `<?php` at the end? Not working for me http://volos-minsk.by/facebook-test-stackoverflow-last.php

Comment: The 1st open tag and the last closing tag was missing...I just edited my answer to add them.