# Can I automatically publish facebook posts on a website from my facebook profile?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to show all the post of my facbook profile on a page of my website.  Can I get this one. Is it possible to get the post from the facebook on a website.

If it is possible then Please tell me the solution.

Instead of this I have read the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10514497/how-to-display-latest-recent-posts-in-my-facebook-page-to-my-website).

I am using this `$token = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='.APP_ID.'&client_secret='.APP_SECRET.'&grant_type=client_credentials';`

to get the accesstoken but is showing the error message `{
   "error": {
      "message": "Error validating application. Invalid application ID.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 101
   }
}`

I am using the right APP_ID AND APP_SECRET.. but not able to get the accesstoken..

Can anybody tell me how to get the required access token for the above question explained.

Answer (score 0):

you need long lived access token.

There is a way to extend this to 60 days. described here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/roadmap/completed-changes/offline-access-removal/

In order to extend the access token you need to make the following request with your short lived access token:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

and how to post on your wall use this script

```
$page_access_token = 'your access token';
$page_id = 'page id';
$data['message'] = "";
$data['access_token'] = <Your access token>;
$post_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$page_id.'/feed';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $post_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```